# c++ Text not showing on screen

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, text

I am trying to print text to my screen using this code.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {      
glutInit(&argc, argv);

glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);

int WindowHandle = glutCreateWindow("Maze");

if (WindowHandle < 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not create a new rendering window.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//Initialize OpenGL
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

//Initialize the viewport
glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);

//Initialize OpenGL projection matrix
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0.0f, 640.0f, 480.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f, 2.0f);

//Clear back buffer
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

//Create font
GLuint textureName;
glGenTextures(1, &textureName);
PixelPerfectGLFont font;
try {
    font.Create("fonts\\quad20.glf", textureName);
}
catch(GLFontError::InvalidFile) {
    cerr << "Cannot load font\n";
    abort();
}

//Draw some stuff
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity( );
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

try {
    font.Begin();
    font.TextOut("hello world", 50, 50, 0);
}
catch(GLFontError::InvalidFont) {
    cerr << "Trying to draw with an uninitialized font\n";
    abort();
}
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glLoadIdentity();


glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

Place this code in a main.cpp file and it will run (assuming you have linkers right)

on top of the code I have

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
#include "glfont.h"
```

to use glfont.h you add `using namespace std;` on top (or else it throws compile errors)

So... when i run the application it only shows a white screen with no text showing.

Can someone please tell me what im doing wrong?

p.s. glfont can be found here http://students.cs.byu.edu/~bfish/glfontdl.php

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please tell me what im doing wrong?

Everything.

That's not how you render with GLUT at all. You're supposed to register callbacks that will be called when GLUT is ready to display stuff. You never swap buffers or anything, so you're not going to see stuff. And so on.

Look at *any* GLUT example you can find, and you'll see that it doesn't look like this.

Before you start playing around with text rendering, you should first understand regular rendering.